# undefined name in a class

Tags: python, class, self

Why does this produce `undefined name x`? It is declared twice and set globally.

```
class Pet():
    global x
    x = 0
    def __init__(self):
        global x
        x=0

    def getX():
        global x
        print x
```

Comment: Python 2.7.6 here, NOT reproducible... :(

Comment: thanks for the reply but it still doesn't work

Comment: If you want all instances of the `Pet` class to share the attribute `x` you don't need `global`.

Comment: I don't really use globals so I don't want to say for sure, but I  think you have to declare a global before you reference it with the `global` keyword.  In other words, you need to put `x=0` in module scope.

Comment: i'm using python 2.7.3. Does that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 5):

Um... no. Global means "it has been declared in global scope, so look for it there", but you *haven't* declared it there.  Try

```
x = 1

class Pet():
    global x
    x = 0
    def __init__(self):
        global x
        x=0

    def getX(self):
        print x
```

You didn't give getX a `self` argument, which also gives an error.

I also have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with all these globals; it kind of defeats the purpose of having nice, self-contained classes.

Unless you are doing something odd, your code probably *should* be something like

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x = x
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)
```

Comment: if i'm honest, neither do I. Earlier I did everything without a class and just started in the file. Then I had some problems so I had to add the global statements.

Comment: It solved the problem, thank you! Does every def needs a self argument?

Comment: @user2883786: yes, every method needs a self argument. (Exceptions are class methods, which take a class argument, and static methods, which take neither, but unless you are explicitly making one of those don't worry about them.)